# installing multilib still doesn't resolve -ltinfo when attempting to build a 32-bit binary with -lcurses

Tags: compiling, 32-bit, static-linking

Trying to build a 32-bit app on kubuntu 18.04.  I've got it to the point where I can use -m32 to compile my code in 32-bit mode, and am able to build a trivial app (once I installed multilibs).  But now I'm trying to build an app that uses -lcurses, and ld is complaining about an incompatible X86-64 version of -ltinfo (which I assume is the 'terminfo' library - and is called in by my invoking the curses library).  Specifically:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so when searching for -ltinfo
```

I've got cc -m32 on my final build line, and it's not complaining about any other libraries.

For what it's worth, if I go with the system defaults and allow my app to build as a 64-bit binary, everything builds - so I'm assuming I'm asking for all the right libraries, etc.  It's just that the app doesn't *work right* as a 64-bit app, and before I go down the path of figuring out why *that* is, I thought I'd try to build it as a 32-bit app - which worked 20 years ago when I did my first 'proof of concept' linux build for this app ;-)

Is there some other way to invoke the 'ld' command to get the proper 32-bit libraries to load?  Or do I have to install yet another 32-bit library package for -lcurses to work in 32-bit mode?

Comment: My understanding of multiarch in regard to the build process is rudimentary, but afaik it is only the headers that are common - you *will* generally need to install the `:i386` versions of any actual libraries required. In fact, it looks like `libncurses5:i386` depends on `libtinfo5:i386` so I'm surprised the latter wasn't installed when you installed the former.

Comment: It *is* there.  Not sure why it isn't picked up.   

$ locate libtinfo|grep i386
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtinfo5:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtinfo5:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtinfo5:i386.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtinfo5:i386.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtinfo5:i386.triggers

I've given up on trying to build this stuff in 32-bit mode at this point.  Gonna bite the bullet and go 64-bit, dealing with a bunch of 'pointer and int are not the same size' problems - but such is sloppily written code...

Comment: OK so it looks like you need to install the `-dev:i386` package(s) and apparently can do so without conflict. What's missing is the symlink `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so -> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5` which installation of the architecture dependent -dev package creates. You may need to do the same for `libncurses5-dev:i386`. I suggest you try first with the `--dry-run` apt flag to make sure there are no conflicts on your particular system.

Comment: Hmmm.  I thought I *had* installed the 386 dev stuff, and I *do* have a lot of stuff in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.  But libtinfo is *not* there - even though 'locate libtinfo' said it was.  Perhaps it was there the last time locate updated its database, but was subsequently uninstalled.  Thanks.